# How to show "No result found" alert message if no result found using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, filter

How to show an alert message if user query not found. When user type in the searchbar something like "asdfdsas" user should get an alert like "no result is found". Is there any way to get that using javascript?

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: where in your code would you like this alert?

Comment: I'm betting you're going to run out of users, if you're showing an alert every time a key is stroked.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you want an alert(alert could be quite annoying) or a message.

If you want a message instead.

Here's a solution, and mind the comments:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue, noResult;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    
    // no-result-found element
    noResult = document.querySelector('p');
    
    // determine if any result is found, false by default
    let found = false;
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
            // set found to true
            found = true;
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    
    // if no results are found, show no-result-found element, and vice versa
    if(found) {
        noResult.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        noResult.style.display = '';
        // if you want an alert instead, uncomment the next line and remove the previous line
        // alert('No result found');
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Make an element for showing no result, hidden by default -->
<p style="display: none;">No result found</p>
```